# NGINX Rewrite url subdomain to maindomain with variable

Tags: nginx

I should rewrite url

**subdomain.test.com/login?xxxxxx**

to

**test.com/login?xxxxxx**

how can I configure try files part for that?

.htaccess wont possible

Comment: What is your `nginx.conf` contents? By the way, you can't make queries from one domain to another with `try_files`, as maximum you can use different location under single `server {}` directive, as far as I know.